# Is there a way to use an object from a list only if it exists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects, lets say DataTables.

Is it possible to use an object from the list only if it exists?

For example, if the TableList contains 5 DataTables named a,b,c,d,e.

```
if (TableList.Any(t => t.TableName == "a"))
{
     TableList.First(t => t.TableName == "a").DoStuff();

     //OR

     DataTable TheReturnOf_a = TableList.First(t => t.TableName == "a");
}
else if (TableList.Any(t => t.TableName == "f"))
{
     TableList.First(t => t.TableName == "f")).DoMoreStuff();
}
```

Comment: you can use `FirstOrDefault` and check that returned value is not null if your object is referenced type.

Comment: You may also consider using a `Dictionary` where the Key is the `TableName`. This might help if `TableList` had large numbers of entries and you were doing lots of lookups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `TableList` has an element type that is a reference type, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` to return the first match or null, then the null conditional operator to only call the method if the target is non-null:

```
TableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "a")?.DoStuff();
```

So your original code is equivalent to:

```
var tableA = TableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "a");
if (tableA != null)
{
    tableA.DoStuff();
}
else
{
    TableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "f").DoStuff();
}
```

Alternatively, if you're going to do the same thing to the table you end up using, and you're just trying to get the right table, you could use or null coalescing operator:

```
// Find an "a" table if possible, but revert to an "f" table otherwise.
var table = TableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "a") ??
            TableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "f");
// Call DoStuff() on the table - handling the case where there isn't an
// "a" or an "f" table.
table?.DoStuff();
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I'm very appreciative. What if I do need to run a different function based on which table it is?

Comment: @TheNextFreud: Then you'd use the if/else as per the middle part of my answer. And if you might want to do things on three different tables, it would depend on whether you were returning from the `if` block or not, but you may end up using multiple nested if/else.

Comment: What if I make a bool function with an out parameter? That way my if statements will already set the table to use, otherwise move on to the next block.. ?

Comment: @TheNextFreud: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that, but please be aware that I've answered the question you originally asked - continuing to ask additional questions in comments is not the way Stack Overflow works. If you have an alternative idea for solving your own question, I suggest you try it yourself - you could add an answer for your own question if it works out. If it doesn't work but you don't understand why, ask a new question *just* about that.